# ST STM32H743XI (ARM M7 based) MCU - ADC Configuration

Tags: adc, stm32, st, arm7

I am using the ST STM32H743XI (ARM M7 based) MCU,

I want to use the ADC to measure 7 Hall sensors (use both slow and fast channels),
i need the conversion time for all seven ADC channels to be the same,

How to make the conversion time for the slow and fast channels be exactly the same?

Answer (score 1):

In [Reference manual](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/reference_manual/group0/c9/a3/76/fa/55/46/45/fa/DM00314099/files/DM00314099.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00314099.pdf) section 24.3.13: Channel-wise programmable sampling time:

> Constraints on the sampling time for fast and slow channels: For each channel, SMP[2:0] bits must be programmed to respect a minimum sampling time as specified in the ADC characteristics section of the datasheets.

So difference between fast and slow channels is only in minimum sample time.

To have same conversion time check section 24.3.17: Timing in same datasheet. Easiest way would be to have all parameters equal (sample time, data resolution).

If you actualy want to have same sampling frequncy on all channels then you only need to have conversion time smaller (and not equal) than period of ADC.

Comment: Difference is not only in minimum sample time needed, 

in 24.3.17: Timing (as well as in 24.3.13) we can see the conversion time is depended on ADC clock frequency,

the clock frequency of Fast and slow channels is different (see Datasheet -  6.3.20 16-bit ADC characteristics ).

So to have same conversion time between all channels i need to take the difference in frequency into account,

the question, is there another way to do this?
if no, should i set the clock for ADC to be 10 MHz which is supported by the slow channels or may i use higher frequency?

Comment: @PeterBerger It would be easiest to use 10 MHz if it is enough,but you can use different ADC frequncies and calculate appropriate parameters, but you will be constrained by discrete values for sample time.

Comment: What do you mean by:
but you will be constrained by discrete values for sample time